# rxjs one sequence multiple subscriptions take x

Tags: rxjs

Let's say I have an rxjs observable created from an array of values:

```
let obs = Observable.fromArray([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
```

on some button click, we do this:

```
obs.take(2).toArray().subscribe(x => {
    console.log('the value is:', x); // and the value will be [1,2]
})
```

The button is clicked again, and again we get [1,2].
The desired behavior is, however, to receive [3,4], and then [5,6].

How would you go about doing this in rxjs?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than taking out a subscription when the button is clicked, I would model the clicks as a stream with something like this:

```
const clicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('trigger'), 'click');
```

You can use `bufferWithCount(2)` to reduce your `obs` stream in the desired way. You can then combine the streams as appropriate. For example, if you'd like to match each click with a new set (1:1, without skipping any), you could use `zip`:

```
const subscription = clicks.zip(obs.bufferWithCount(2), (x, y) => y)
                           .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Here's a working example: http://jsbin.com/vonegoq/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: hmmm...i am using ng2 and rxjs 5.0.0-beta.2 and it is saying bufferWithCount is not a function. maybe i'm doing something stupid

Comment: Looking at the rxjs5 source, it looks like it's just named "bufferCount" now.

Comment: Ah, and if I'd looked properly, I'd have noticed it was mentioned here, too: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md